# Given a general solution $y_1,y_2$ of $y''+p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0$ take $y_2=v y_1$ and show $\frac{dw}{dx} + (2 \frac{y_1'}{y_1}+p)w=0$ for $v'=w$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $\{y_1(x),y_2(x)\}$ is a fundamental solution set of the ODE $y''+p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0$, I need to show the following:

Let the function $v(x)$ be such that $y_2(x)=v(x)y_1(x)$. Show that $w=v'$ satisfies the ODE

$$\frac{dw}{dx} + (2 \frac{y_1'}{y_1}+p)w=0\dots (*)$$.

I'm pretty lost on how to do this one.  First I took the first and second derivatives of $v(x) = \frac{y_2(x)}{y_1(x)}$ then subbed it back into $(*)$, but I'm not getting any cancellation that I can tell.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

the method you are after is the method of fining the second solution of second order linear ode, given you know one solution. suppose you have $$y_1'' + py_1 + qy_1 = 0.\tag 1$$ look for a second solution in the form of $$  y = uy_1, y' = u'y_1 + uy_1', y''= u''y_1 + 2u'y_1' + uy_1'' \tag 2$$
subbing $(2)$ in $(1),$  we have $$ u''y_1 + 2u'y_1' + uy_1''+p(u'y_1+uy_1')+ quy_1 = 0\to u''y_1 + 2u'y_1' +pu'y_1 = 0 $$ which can be simplified to $$w = u', w' + \left(\frac{2y_1'+py_1}{y_1}\right)w = 0.$$